# Drupal 8 cannot find SoapClient class

Tags: php, soap, drupal, drupal-modules, soap-client

I'm trying to consume a remote webservice but it doesnt work and I'm new to drupal.
below is my code:

```
namespace Drupal\mymodule\mymoduleAPI;
class RemoteConnection {

  public function create() {

    $default = array( 
            // We shall only enable TRACING & EXCEPTION for dev 
            'trace' => 1, 
            'exceptions' => true, 
            'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE, 
            'features' => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS,
        );


    $myServerEndPointUrl = "wsdl server address";
    return new SoapClient($myServerEndPointUrl , $default);     
  }
}
```

This gives me the following error

> Fatal error: Class 'Drupal\mymodule\mymoduleapi\SoapClient' not found
>   in C:\wamp\www\drupalnew\modules\

So am I doing something wrong? I already checked the Soap extension and tested it outside drupal and found it to work fine.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a use command after your namespace:

```
use \SoapClient;
```

e.g.

```
namespace Drupal\module_name\Plugin\Block;

use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;
use SoapClient;
```

Answer (score 1):

SoapClient is in the global namespace, so when accessing it from within your own namespace, use '\' in front of the class name, like:

```
return new \SoapClient($myServerEndPointUrl , $default);
```

Further info [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.faq.php#language.namespaces.faq.globalclass)